# Programmatically Download RDP file from AWS once a EC2 instance its launch with it java sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

There are a few things I require help on, I am currently working with AWS ec2 instances. I have successfully started a server using an Image I have created in AWS and launch the image to multiple instances with the help of the Java SDK. To let me access these instances that I have launched, I understand that in the aws console I am able to get RDP File when I click on download Remote Desktop File when I click on the instance but I am checking if the java SDK provides a way to get the RDP file directly without having me to go into the console.

Comment: Look at the relevant documentations first

Comment: I have looked to the relevant documentation on the JDK it does state the for downloading the file.